# Are both square roots of -1 valid in Euler's Identity?

Tags: complex-numbers, pi

In every case I've ever seen, Euler's Identity is written as

$e^{i\pi} + 1 = 0$

with the "positive" $\sqrt{-1}$.  However, my understanding is that both $i$ and $-i$ are valid for $\sqrt{-1}$.

Does this mean that

$e^{-i\pi} + 1 = 0$

is also a valid identity?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: Yes. More generally, $\overline{e^z}=e^{\overline z}$ where $\overline w$ is the complex conjugate.

Comment: In particular, when $e^z$ is real, then $e^{z}=e^{\overline z}.$

Comment: If one of these comments can be posted as an answer, I'll mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

$$e^{-i\pi} =\cos (-\pi)+i\sin(-\pi)=-1$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $\ker(\exp)=2\pi i \Bbb Z$, we also have $e^{i\pi-2\pi i}=e^{i\pi}$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $\theta \in \mathbb R$ then
$$
e^{-i\theta} =\cos(-\theta) + i\sin(-\theta) = \cos(\theta) - i\sin(\theta).
$$
Plugging in $\theta = \pi$ yields
$$
e^{-i\pi} = -1.
$$